# React.js : Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

This error is causing the entire page to not display. I have to load a project locally (I did not write it) but this is the first thing that pops up in the console.

Code:

```
class Panel extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      DropdownTitle: 'Screen',
      setScreenByCookie: true
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    var roleCookie = cookie.load('role');
    roleCookie = roleCookie.toLowerCase();
    const accountId = cookiefetch('accountId','');
    var accid = accountId.toLowerCase();
    const overrideCompany = cookiefetch('overrideCompany', '');
    if(overrideCompany != '') {
      var title = "Screen ("+overrideCompany+")";
      this.setState({DropdownTitle: title});
    } else {
      this.setState({DropdownTitle: 'Screen'});
    }
    var roleCookie = roleCookie.toLowerCase();
    if (roleCookie == 'administrator' || roleCookie == "adminread") {

        dispatch(getCompaniesDropdown());

    } else {
      dispatch(getCompany(accid));
      dispatch(getDropdown(accid));
      //dispatch(companyDropdownAction(false, accid, accid));
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
Panel.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at Panel.componentWillMount (Panel.js:47)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:210)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.ReactCompositeComponent_mountComponent [as mountComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:37)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:225)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.ReactCompositeComponent_mountComponent [as mountComponent] (ReactPerf.js:66)
    at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:37)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:241)
    at ReactDOMComponent._createContentMarkup (ReactDOMComponent.js:591)
    at ReactDOMComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMComponent.js:479)
```

Line 47 is the first use of toLowerCase:
roleCookie = roleCookie.toLowerCase();

Comment: what will `cookie.load('role')` returns?

Comment: Stupid question, but have you checked that the 'role' cookie is set on the page you are testing with? Also what is `cookie` and `cookiefetch`?

Comment: Is that a jQuery `load` in there?

Answer (score 1):

`cookie.load` returns `undefined` if that cookie value doesn't exist. Instead of naively converting the value to lower case, you'll need to first check if it exists. E.g.:

```
roleCookie = roleCookie ? roleCookie.toLowerCase() : roleCookie;
```

Answer (score 0):

For every data fetching and assignment that may face `undefined`, you better make a fallback that depends on your code just like bellow:

```
accountId = cookiefetch('accountId','') ? cookiefetch('accountId','') : 'someDefaultValue'
```

Also you can make an exception for overriding it via conditions

```
if(accountId) { var accid = accountId.toLowerCase(); }
```

by the way do not use `componentWillMount()` any more and use `componentDidMount()`. Async is async :)